# Detect Software Keyboard state in android lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-softkeyboard, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have used the code given below in my app to detect whether keyboard is visible or not. I am able to use it for android versions other than lollipop. When running the app on a lollipop device the below code is not working. It would be of great help if anyone could correct the code if it is wrong or provide any alternate solutions.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {@Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) {
            //keyboard is visible
        }
    }
});
```